# Throwing numberformatexception regardless

Tags: java

Im writing a class for a card that takes in two string parameters,

When I check the string if it's an "a" it throws the `NumberFormatException` error.

```
Card(String s, String  f) 
{
    suit = s;
    if(f == "a")
    {
        value = 11;
    }

    else if (f == "j" || f == "k" || f == "q")
    {
        value = 10;
    }

    else
    {
        value = Integer.parseInt(f);
    }
    face  = f; 
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Be sure to include an example run of your program.

Comment: Also read about [how to compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings with `==`. That only compares the "shallow" reference values of the two strings, whether if they point to the same string object (most). You have to use the `.equals` function of the string to check equality with strings.

Comment: I knew that, my brain is just fried from a long day. Thanks!